# kubernetes preStop gracefull shutdown timeout without hook

Tags: kubernetes

I want to set the parameter

> terminationGracePeriodSeconds

to some value so that kubernetes will let my pods finish their work. I know that normaly you will use this parameter combined with a preStop hook of type http or exec, but what if I only set this parameter without any hook? will Kubernetes still wait for the terminationGracePeriodSeconds before it removes the container?

Answer (score 2):

There is no actual coupling between `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` spec and a definition of a `preStop` and you can define the `pod.Spec.TerminationGracePeriodSeconds` value to your custom needs per-container.

Meanwhile, the value to which the graceful shutdown period is set will affect the time left for your container to terminate gracefully when you have a `preStop` hook configured as the both execute in a synchronous serial fashion and the total time specified in the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` includes the `preStop` hook execution time.

As an example, if you specify 30 (seconds) as the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` value and the `preStop` hook takes 25 seconds to terminate, then the container is left with only 5 seconds to terminate gracefully before being shutdown abruptly by the *Kubernetes* Manager.

Comment: there is some kind of coupling - if u configure a hook, and it finished before the terminationGracePeriodSeconds, than kubernetes will kill the pod earlier. if your script is longer, it will kill it after terminationGracePeriodSeconds seconds. but in any case, I thinks you are right about they are not being coupled, because SIGTERM is graceful, after that kubernetes sends SIGKILL.